# Вывести картинку из БД MySql

Tags: php, mysql

Пытаюсь вывести картинку из Mysql, но всё время вылазит ошибка(скрин ниже). Всего есть два файла.

Первый `articles.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Статьи</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Статьи</h1>
            <a href='admin' id="adm">Панель администратора</a>

        <p>
            <h3>Загруженные изображения</h3> 
            <?php 
                mysql_connect ( 'localhost', 'root', '' ); 
            mysql_query( 'utf8_general ci' ); 
            mysql_select_db ( 'blog' ); 
            $query = "SELECT id FROM images"; 
            $res = mysql_query( $query ); 
            while( $img = mysql_fetch_array( $res ) ) { 
              echo '<img src="image.php?id='.$img['id'].'" />'; 
            } 
            ?>
        </p>

            <footer>
                <p>тестовая CRM<br>Copyright &copy; 2015
                </p>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

И файл обработчик `image.php`:

```
<?php 
    // Соединяемся с сервером БД 
    mysql_connect ( 'localhost', 'root', '' ); 
    mysql_query( 'SET NAMES cp1251' ); 
    mysql_select_db ( 'blog' ); 

   if ( isset( $_GET['id'] ) ) { 
  // Здесь $id номер изображения 
  $id = (int)$_GET['id']; 
  if ( $id > 0 ) { 
    $query = "SELECT `content` FROM `images` WHERE `id`=".$id; 
    // Выполняем запрос и получаем файл 
    $res = mysql_query($query); 
    if ( mysql_num_rows( $res ) == 1 ) { 
      $image = mysql_fetch_array($res); 
      // Отсылаем браузеру заголовок, сообщающий о том, что сейчас будет передаваться файл изображения
      header("Content-type: image/jpeg"); 
      // И  передаем сам файл 
      echo $image['content']; 
    } 
  } 
} 
?>
```

Картинки уже имеются в базе. Храню их в BLOB. 
[image: Скрин ошибки]

Comment: А при запросе http://localhost/crm/image.php?id=10 напрямую из браузера что выдает?

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev пишет object not found!

Comment: Значит проблема не в скрипте. Проверяйте, правильно ли указано название файла `image.php` и почему он недоступен для веб сервера.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего вы используете версию PHP, в которой использованные функции для работы с MySQL помечены устаревшими, о чём PHP и сообщает. Но вы по какой-то причине этого не замечаете. Возможно у вас отключен вывод предупредений, возможно вы не читаете логи веб-сервера, возможно вы просто-напросто не запускали `image.php` напрямую. В любом случае заголовки документа меняются. В результате команда `header("Content-type: image/jpeg");` не срабатывает.

Простым и неправильным решением будет подавить вывод предупреждений функцией `mysql_connect()`. Для этого в файле `image.php` поставьте `@` перед `mysql_connect ( 'localhost', 'root', '' );` Должно получиться так:

```
@mysql_connect ( 'localhost', 'root', '' );
```

---

Более правильным и более сложным решением, было бы избежать использования функции `header("Content-type: image/jpeg");`. Попутно это избавит код от множества дополнительных подключений к базе данных, но сделает его менее универсальным.

Файл `image.php` не понадобится. В файле `articles.php` замените

это:

```
$query = "SELECT id FROM images"; 
$res = mysql_query( $query ); 
while( $img = mysql_fetch_array( $res ) ) { 
    echo '<img src="image.php?id='.$img['id'].'" />'; 
}
```

на это:

```
$query = "SELECT `content` FROM `images`"; 
$res = mysql_query( $query ); 
if ( mysql_num_rows( $res ) > 0 )
    while( $img = mysql_fetch_array( $res ) )
        echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($img['content']).'" />';
```

---

Ещё более правильным и сложным решением будет замена усаревших функций работы с MySQL на [современные](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.mysqli.php).

Comment: спасибо за совет, я оказывается просто не туда положил папку image.php и всё было из за этого. @GVA